# Badly visible element shadow

Tags: android, angular-material

I am creating the app that using material design elements. I tried to add shadow for two rectangles (white and blue).

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:translationZ="4dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:translationZ="4dp"/>
```

For white rectangle the shadow is well, but for the blue one the shadow is invisible in fact (especially right side shadow).

[image]

How can I improve the visibility of the shadow?

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because the blue is of course way darker, than the white, so the shadow has way less contrast and "disappears". So it is more like an optical illusion. Look at the image below, I just cut off the colored rectangles, and as you can see, the shadow is the same one. You could make the shadow a bit darker (reduce the opacity a bit), to make it appear "more visible".

[image]

I made a little example with your colors above, on the left there is the same box shadow for the white and the blue box. Obviously the shadow of the blue box is a bit less visible due to the brightness of the box. The shadow of the blue box on the right has a slightly increased opacity (+10%) which makes the shadow a bit more noticable.

[image]

Comment: Matthias thanks, how can I do shadow a bit darker programmatically or using xml?

Comment: To be hoonest, I have no "best practise" for Android here, since I rarely do stuff for Android. I just found this question and had some "theroetical" knowledge to share. Maybe it is a possibility to tie the shadow opacity to the luminosity of the color?

Comment: I don't know how to control the opacity of a shadow using standard libraries, only if I do everything myself, but this is a very large piece of work.

Comment: I looked at several google apps, and to me it looks like they also don't adjust the shadow. Maybe this is just an optical illusion they all live with. **Disclaimer again** Maybe there IS an good workaround. If someone with more Android Knowledge hase something to share, I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: This is an important question. When I make a shadow manually through a gradient, visibility is better and more realistic. When I use Google's tools, I often don't see a shadow at all. But it is very hard to do a shadow manually for all objects and tasks.